# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pelican-3.6.3.dist-info'

Tags: 14.04, python, pelican

I run  `pip install pelican markdown`

I got this error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pelican-3.6.3.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/begueradj/.pip/pip.log
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is possible to install it as a global site-package, I think it is better to look into python virtual environments.

**1. use virtualenv:**

Install virtualenv using sudo

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

then you can create a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv pelican
```

and activate it:

```
. pelican/bin/activate
```

(note the dot+space at the begining). You can then run

```
pip install pelican markdown
```

to install it at this virtual environment. After done working with this you can run

```
deactivate
```

to deactivate the environment. When you want to work on your project again, you'll have to activate that environment again.

**2. virtualenvwrapper**

virtualenvwrapper is a tool for making it easier to manage multiple virtual environments. You can install it by typing

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
```

then create a virtual environment using

```
mkvirtualenv pelican
```

and install your packages

```
pip install pelican markdown
```

You can then deactivate this environment with

```
deactivate
```

When you want to work with this environment again run:

```
workon pelican
```

**Installation as a global site-package**

If you insist to install it as a global site-package run

```
sudo pip install pelican markdown
```

Comment: Thank you, but the main issue I asked about is not addressed by your answer. I upvoted for the other alternatives you gave me though.

Comment: @Begueradj, thanks for the upvote. Since you want to install it as a global site-package, use the last option ("Installation as a global site-package").

Comment: Yes, I will try your solution in the coming hours. If one of them works I will accept your answer. Thank you